# JSON - data.items is undefined

Tags: jquery, undefined, each

I can not wrap in my `data.items` because it contains arrays of arrays, and suddenly I feel that it is lost.
`data.items is undefined`.

I use JQuery to complete with `$.each`.

My JSON listed below:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "name": "factors",
    "items": [
        {
            "name": "type de lieux",
            "value": {
                "appartement": "Appartement",
                "maison individuelle": "Maison individuelle"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "surface",
            "value": {
                "79": "< 80",
                "81": "> 80"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I do this with jQuery, but I return the error message described above:

```
$.each(data['items'], function(i, item) {
    alert('oki');
});
```

What should I do as an amendment?

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: works for me http://jsfiddle.net/nuWT4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to iterate use -

```
var data = {"success":true,"name":"factors","items":[{"name":"type de lieux","value":{"appartement":"Appartement","maison individuelle":"Maison individuelle"}},{"name":"surface","value":{"79":"< 80","81":"> 80"}}]};

$(data.items).each(function(i, item) {
    alert(item.name+" : "+item.value);
});
```

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/rXETR/

Comment: Thank you!
I was able to resolve my concerns from what you've provided!

P.S.: Thanks @f0x for corrections you have made

Answer (score 0):

Taking it one step further:

This example iterates through the nested 'key value' pairs of the object array 'items'.

### **JSON Data**

```
var data = {
  "success": true,
    "name": "factors",
    "items": [{
    "name": "type de lieux",
      "value": {
      "appartement": "Appartement",
        "maison individuelle": "Maison individuelle"
    }
  }, {
    "name": "surface",
    "value": {
      "79": "< 80",
      "81": "> 80"
    }
  }]
};
```

### **Handling the data**

```
$.each(data.items, function (i, val) {
  $.each(val.value, function (key, value) {
    alert('"' + data.name + '" [' + i + '] ' + val.name + '" : "value" -> ' + key + ' ' + value);
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rXETR/6/